# 'Network Error' with axios POST request on safari but works on other browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am using Nodejs for backend and reactjs for frontend.

I've tried solutions from similar posted questions but none seemed to work.

Middleware & routes:

```
const root = path.join(__dirname, '../../build');  
app.use(express.static(root));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
});
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api', routes(app));
```

answer.post.js

```
   try {
      const answer = await Answer.create(answerReq);
      console.log(answer);
      res.send(answer);
    } catch (error) {
      next(new Error(error));
    }
```

Where answer object gets created and is shown on console as expected.
Post request in frontend:

```
const apiEndpoint = "/api/answer";
axios.post(apiEndpoint, { data });
```

Strangest thing is that it works on other browsers but not safari. On safari I just receive 'Network error'.

Edit: Error is shown as an alert

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {
  const expectedError =
    error.response &&
    error.response.status >= 400 &&
    error.response.status < 500;

  if (!expectedError) {
    alert("Error: ", error);
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: don't get you any more detailed response than that?

Comment: Yeah, that is all I get

Comment: Where are you seeing that exactly? Have you tried looking in the browser's Developer Tools to see if there's more info on the console and/or network tools?

Comment: I looked at the console and I got nothing - nothing gets outputted. Sorry, I will add more info shortly on where I output this error.

Comment: Maybe your network requests are being cancelled: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2103

Comment: Errors seem to be the same but no indication on how to solve it though or what it is exactly

Comment: are there any non-ascii characters in `data`. we are observing that non-ascii characters are causing this issue. @Vedo

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding `/` to the end of my endpoint solved the issue (was only happening in Safari) i.e. try `/api/answer/` instead of `/api/answer`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching to node-fetch lib:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Still interested in why the problem is happening when using axios though